# Retrieve ul, li tag which don't have class of name

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How do it get all of `<li>` tags? The code shown is just show off 1 line of `<li>` tags.

```
string id="1-1";
public async void ExampLoad(string id)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string srtHtml = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/appeal");
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(srtHtml);

    List<Models.EnglishDictionary> arrays = new List<Models.EnglishDictionary>();
    var NewListNodeHtml = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("entryContent");
    if(NewListNodeHtml!=null)
    {
        var SenseBlock = NewListNodeHtml.Descendants("div").Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("id", "") == id);
        if(SenseBlock!=null)
        {
            foreach(var node in SenseBlock)
            {
               Dictionaries = new Models.EnglishDictionary();
               var ul = node.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "extraexamps");
               if(ul!=null)
               {
                   Dictionaries.Examp = ul.InnerText.Trim();
               }
               arrays.Add(Dictionaries);
             }
         }
     }
     lstExample1_1.ItemsSource = arrays;
}
```

I'm not enough point to post an photos.

Here link photos:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/617918

Comment: In your question title, do you mean "get rid of" (remove)? Can you post an example of what input/output you want? Text is fine, it doesn't need to be a photo. If your input is `<html><body><ul><li>item1</li><li class"style1">item2</li></ul><ul class="listStyle"><li>item3</li><li class"style1">item4</li></ul></body></html>`, what would the output be? If that's not the right input you're talking about, please add your own.

Comment: I just want to get all information inside li tags. No, 
<ul style="dfa fd"> <li class="eg">Item1</li><li class="eg">item2></li></ul>
That results which I want.
Item1
Item2.
My Top code is just show off item1.

Comment: What about classes/names? You want to get the <li> only if it the class matches? I didn't understand what you said about class/name in the title.